# I want Near Users Posts show on top. I also save the location in posts

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am making simple social app. But i want near people posts show on top. here's code for showing posts in Recyclerview. I also Save Location latitude and longitude in Firestore Posts.

Just Give me Idea what kind of query I should add.

Here is User Location where he will post

[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_list);
    ProductsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("data");
    recyclerhome = findViewById(R.id.recycler_home);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DataListActivity.this);
    recyclerhome.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    Query query = ProductsRef.whereEqualTo("pname","Workname");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<data> options =
        new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<data>()
            .setQuery(query, data.class)
            .build(); 
        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<data, ProductViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<data, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final data model) {
                    holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                    holder.txtProductDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
                    holder.txtProductPrice.setText( model.getCategory());

                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("pid", model.getPid());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false);
                    ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };

        recyclerhome.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any field in your data document that saves the distance between point A and user point else you would have set a query on that field in ascending or descending order. But in your case I would suggest you to take all the 'data' collection data and store in a List and then sort that list (Sorting a Stack). Then your nearest users will always be on top of the list to which you can later pass it to your recyclerview.

Comment: @HritikGupta data is just a model class for getting and setting data from firestore

Comment: I was referring to your collection whose name is also data. Store all the data from that collection in a List<data> myDataList = new ArrayList();